# Send webhooks async when triggered by Symfony/Doctrine events

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous, events, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement an event system to send webhooks to various services when triggered by a doctrine event. I'm confident that's a fairly common problem but my research seems to only cover the basics.
I find it easy to do, but seem to have a hard time doing it "right". Since it's a side effect that I don't want to have performance impact, I'm trying to do most of the webhook related logic asynchronously. Say there's three services that may be user configured to be notified when a specific event related to an entity type happens.

Here's an idea I find is lacking something or too complex for what it needs to do:

1. `#[AsDoctrineListener]` listens for persists/updates/deletes
2. An **asynchronous** Message is sent with the entity class+ID (and diff in case of update)
3. A handler receives the message (using `messenger:consume`) and emits a specific **sync** event, ie `OrderCreatedEvent`
4. Each third party API then has its own `#[AsEventListener]` that picks up the `OrderCreatedEvent` and looks up the API's config, formats the payload and prepares authentication
5. If configured, the listener sends another **async** message which is a generic `SendWebhookMessage` that contains payload, url and authentication
6. Another handler then sends the actual HTTP request

This way seems to decouple the actual event, and the side effects from looking up webhook configs to actually sending them. It seems quite complicated for something that probably doesn't need to be? I'm a sole developer of an ERP system and want to make sure that if anyone picks it up, or if I come back to it later I can wrap my head around it.
Is that an overkill or is there a better way to make it robust and ensure that a bad webhook configuration or a network error doesn't affect the initial event, or hinder performance?

The project is running on PHP 8.3 and Symfony 6.4

Thanks!